# Need some direction in building an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am building an iPhone app where I show the closest specialty restaurants to the user.  I am using a navigation based application to do the development.

1. I want to let the user press a button on the first screen that allows him/her to go to screen 2.
2. From screen 2, here the user will see a table of all the restaurants close to the user.
3. Once the user selects a restaurant from this table, the user is taken to a third screen
4. Here, the user will see a map where the user will see where he/she is, and where the restaurant is located.

I will be using the CoreLocation framework to initially calculate the user's location, and then use this to search the database for locations close by.  What I am confused about is, what method should I be doing this in the RootViewController?  Would I place the button in the viewDidLoad() method, which would then trigger this method:

```
-(void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
                                                            fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this.

1. Use a UITabBarController with three tabs, one for each of your views.  When you want to auto-transition to the next screen, use `[myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:]` or `[myTabBarController setSelectedViewController:]`.
2. Pattern it after a flip-view "Utility Application."  You can create a project using the Utility Application template for example code.  The major difference is that instead of flipping from the backside to the front side, you're flipping to a third view controller.
3. Use a UINavigationController and `pushViewController:animated:` the second and third view controllers.

The actual CLLocationManagerDelegate stuff should probably live it the app delegate.  Let the app delegate manage "global" data for the app.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  The app I am trying to emulate is www.timmyme.com which shows you the closest "Tim Horton's" coffee shop to you.  Which approach would be best to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd go with a TabBarController based app.  One tab for the map, one tab for the listing, and maybe one for filter settings like "has WiFi" or "has drive-thru."  (I don't know this chain, these may not be relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a singleton class named for instance `CurrentLocationProvider` with all the logic connected with updating location incapsulated inside it and call it's `beginUpdateLocation` method in AppDelegate. It will be also great to provide user with a button that updates location explicitly when fired.